# Validating text(input text is similar to date) in primefaces

Tags: regex, validation, text

I need an expression for the form yyyy-mm-dd(like date format), and I used regular expression : `^(19|20)\d\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$`
But it only includes date till year 2099 but it is not the requirement, how to increase the upper limit to more ? Like 3000-01-01, 5000-01-01... etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
 ^\d{4}[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$
```

I did not test it...

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with the "19|20" you see at the beginning.  That's saying that the year must start with 19 or 20.  You can generalize with by substituting `(19|20)` with `\d\d` which is to say any two digits are allowed.  So the following:

`^\d\d\d\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$`

Whether this is acceptable or not is entirely up to you, though the more flexible you are with these sorts of things, the easier it is for a user to insert a value which they probably didn't mean to insert.

Also do keep in mind that there are other date formats used in the world.  :)